# Returning all matching records using lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with data and a lookup table that shows how they both match

What's the SQL query I use to join the 2 main tables

###### Table 1

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | John |

###### Table 2

| Id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Mexico |

###### Lookup table

| Id1 | Id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 |

I want to return

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| John | Mexico |

How do I do this?

I tried to do an inner join but I don't know how to use the lookup table in the middle.

Comment: With `JOIN`s. What were you attempts? Why didn't they work?

Comment: Please show us your attempt so we can help you.

Comment: You can use this tutorial to learn: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to do an inner join...

You need **two** `JOIN`s

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Country
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Lookup lu ON lu.ID1 = t1.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = lu.ID2
```